# How to use socket.io-client everyware without using special Vue.js librarys?

Tags: vue.js, socket.io

- I would prefere not to use [vue-socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-socket.io) or [vue-socket.io-extended](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-socket.io-extended).
  (Or can someone convince me why I should?)
- I would like to use [socket.io-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client) in multiple components.

I know you can use `socket.io-client` in a component like this:

```html
<!-- SocketIOExample.vue -->
<script>
    import io from "socket.io-client";
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
               socket: {}
            }
        },
        created(){
            this.socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
        },
        mounted(){
            this.socket.on('connect', () => {
                console.log('connected');
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

But how should I do it so that I don't have to connect in every component and so that I can use `socket` globally?

I'm using a Vue cli project.

Comment: "I would prefere not to use vue-socket.io or vue-socket.io-extended. (Or someone convince me why I should.)" Instead, why don't you convince us why you *shouldn't*? These things exist for a reason. Make your life easier instead of being afraid of installing a package.

Comment: I feel that it's odd that everything needs a vue wrapper. I thought that if I would see an example that uses the vanilla socket.io-client that I would understand why I would need or not need the vue-librarys.

Comment: You don't *need* a Vue wrapper, it just saves you the work of having to do it yourself. In general, they're using `Vue.prototype` to do it. https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html